# How to send a S3 bucket file to an external API via POST request

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need an assistance on sending a file stored in S3 bucket over POST request to an external API.
I know the process to send the file. But not able to read the S3 bucket file.
Any help on how to read the S3 bucket file would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide your python code and explain why it does not work? Any error msgs?

Comment: [Amazon S3 examples — Boto3 Docs 1.18.7 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-examples.html)